# C++ Ehlib - Не работает UPDATE у ADODataDriverEh

Tags: c++, sql, access

Здравствуйте
Возникла проблема с ADODataDriverEh
Имеется стандартная цепочка:
ADOConnectionProviderEh - ADODataDriverEh - MemTableEh - DataSource - DBGridEh (с DBNavigator)

у ADODataDriverEh:
выборка:

```
select *
from
  Users
order by id
```

вставка

```
insert into Users
    (Name) 
values
    (:Name)
```

удаление

```
delete from Users
where
  id = :OLD_id
```

обновление

```
update Users
set 
    Name = :Name
where
  id = :OLD_id
```

Выборка, вставка, удаление - работают.
Обновление - Нет
В чем может быть причина?

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Comment: Может быть вы пытаетесь обновить строку, которую ранее удалили.

Comment: нет, ничего не удаляю. все делал по демо проекту DataDriver.ADO.SimpleDemo. все работает, кроме update